# Как создают изометрические игровые карты браузерных игр?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, разработка-игр

Более чем уверен, что используется PHP и jQuery/JavaScript.

Вопрос в следующем: как строится именно карта игрового мира?
Была идея создавать массив со случайными цифрами, например 1 - земля, 2 - дерево и тд., но непонятно толком как все это разместить у клиента в браузере, да еще и сохранять все в базе данных.

Кто-нибудь подскажет?

P.S:
Пока задавал вопрос, пришла мысль.
Можно создать массив (как я предлагал выше), а потом повернуть камеру под определенный угол, и должна получиться графика какая-никакая. Но вот как сохранить все в БД..

Comment: Хорошая книжка по теме: https://www.amazon.com/Making-Isometric-Social-Real-Time-JavaScript/dp/1449304753

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно начать изучение с базы, основ.

1. Что такое серверные языки программирования и как они работают: PHP, Node, ASP.NET, JSP и др. Не сразу сами языки изучать а понять что вообще такое серверный язык и как идёт взаимодействие с клиентом-браузером.
2. Что такое клиентский JavaScript код и как он взаимодействует с сервером, и как вообще браузер взаимодействует с сервером.
3. Как работает отображение игровой анимации в браузере, там есть разные варианты: Canvas, WebGL, SVG, ... Понять что некоторые вещи лучше делать не самому а использовать готовые движки. Есть варианты браузерных движков.
4. Базы данных, их взаимодействие с серверным и клиентским кодом.
5. Математика и геометрия.

Я не говорю что вы это всё не знаете, но из вашего вопроса ясно что есть большие пробелы в знаниях основ веб программирования, с них и надо начать изучение.

Эту всю информацию невозможно написать в одном ответе, это долгая работа в изучении технологий.

По ходу изучения придётся решать много тестовых и обучающих задач.

**Добавлено**

Карты и механика движения в играх может быть реализована по-разному.

1. Самый просто вариант который был в первых стратегических играх это дискретная карта сетка - двумерный массив. Соответственно в одном месте может находиться только один объект карты, и это либо проходная зона, либо стенка. На проходной зоне может стоять юнит. Столкновения и движение рассчитывается очень просто. Про камеру в такой ситуации особенно говорить не стоит, так как имеет место плоский вид сверху, или немного под углом, но угол жёстко зафиксирован.
2. Вариант уже не с дискретной картой, где объекты на карте имеют форму круг или квадрат, и могут размещаться в любой точке координат, координаты могут быть любые дробные числа. Столкновения уже рассчитываются математически. Карта в такой ситуации это набор объектов с их координатами. Возможно даже 3D.
3. Вариант где формы объектов произвольные. Наиболее сложный расчёт столкновений и движения по карте.

Конечно это не все варианты, и у каждого варианта есть много нюансов которые в рамках этого поста нету смысла описывать.